# Merging two directed trees?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

> Since tree height is the main impediment to computational efficiency, a good strategy is to make the root of the shorter tree point to the root of the longer tree.

Does this *really* matter though? I mean if you did it the other way around (merge the longer tree into the shorter) the tree height will only increase by 1. Since an increase of 1 wouldn't make a real difference (would it?), does it really matter which tree is merged into which? Or is there an alternate reason for why the shorter tree is merged into the longer?

Note I am talking about disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear which kind of tree you are talking about (binary search trees, disjoint sets, or any n-ary tree).
But in any case, I think the reason is that although having a an increase of 1 isn't significant, if you do n mergers you end up with an increase of n. This can be significant if you have a data structure that needs lots of mergers (e.g. disjoint sets).

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot to mention the type: I am talking about disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

The quoatation lacks context. For example, in some tree structures single elemenet may have to be inserted one by one (possibly rebalancing the tree, for example - usually you want trees of height O(log n)); maybe this is meant: Then it is easier to insert fewer elements to the larger tree.

Obviously, if a height increase of 1 matters depends in party on how often the height is increased by one :-)

Edit: With [disjoint sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests), it *is* important that the smaller (lower) tree will be added to the bigger.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the type: I'm specifically talking about disjoint sets.

Comment: The [wikipedia article on the data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) has some discussion.